# ¿Cómo puedo lograr que se ejecute en el mismo SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

Estoy creando un Store Procedures en MySQL y me gustaría saber si existe una manera de imprimir los datos en la misma sentencia como en el ejemplo a continuación:

**Sentencia de Sql Server** `print ('Hola Charly ' + cast (@cont as varchar))`

Anexo una imagen en la que se muestra como se ejecutan las consultas por separado en MySQL.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_test`()
BEGIN
 DECLARE cont INT;
 SET cont = 0;
  WHILE cont < 5 DO
    IF cont < 3 THEN 
        SELECT 'Hola Charlie';
        SELECT CAST(cont AS CHAR);
    ELSE
        SELECT 'Hello friends';
        SELECT CAST(cont AS CHAR);
    END IF;
    SET cont = cont + 1;
  END WHILE;
END
```

[image: Imagen de ejecución]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para concatenar partes de tu selección puedes hacerlo con la funcion `CONCAT()` quedando de la siguiente manera

```
SELECT CONCAT("Mensaje",@variable)...
```

Comment: Los concatena sin espacio que los separe ¿cómo puedo hacer que se muestren con espacio?

Comment: Solo añade un espacio entre los datos con coma `SELECT CONCAT("Mensaje"," ",@variable)...`